# Get multiple drop down menus without drop down items appearing under appropriate element

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create multiple drop down menus within a nav element.  Things work as expected besides the elements displayed when a user hovers over the menu items are displayed below the first element, instead of whichever element was selected.

Here's the code in codepen

https://codepen.io/robinreborn/pen/BxRKEa

HTML

```
<nav class="header-nav">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="/about-the-company.php">About the Company</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/our-team.php">Management Team</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="/the-science.php">The Science</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/what-it-tests.php">What is tests?</a>
            <a href="/select-research.php">Select Research?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">      
        <a href="/products.php">Products</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/our-assessments">Our Assessments</a>
            <a href="/holland-interest-profiler">Holland Interest Profiler</a>
            <a href="/decision-making-instrument">Decision Making Instrument</a>
            <a href="/perspective-taking-instrument">Perspective Taking Instrument</a>
            <a href="/admin-review">Admin Review</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/blog.php">Blog</a>
    <a href="/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="/login.php">Login</a>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown {
display:inline; 
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}`
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set positioning on your parent element.

So on the dropdown class add

```
position: relative
```

and set a left position on your absolute layer:

```
left: 0
```

Pen is here: https://codepen.io/cidicles/pen/YLVGjQ